# How to load a yaml file from url to process in python?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file stored at URL location. How do I load it into python for processing?
This is the code I use to read then simply print it out to verify. But I do not see the yaml file format, looks like html to me.
code:

```
import yaml
import urllib
from urllib import request

    x = urllib.request.urlopen("https://git.myplace.net/projects/groups%2users.yaml")
    User_Object = yaml.load(x)
    print(User_Object)
...
```

The output looks like:

```
anch:create-branch-action":{"serverCondition":false}});}(_PageDataPlugin));</script><meta name="application-name" content="Bitbucket"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/s/-1051105741/5ab4b55/261/1.0/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.bitbucket.server.bitbucket-webpack-INTERNAL:favicon/favicon.ico" /><link rel="search" href="https://git.cnvrmedia.net/plugins/servlet/opensearch-descriptor" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Bitbucket code search"/></head><body class="aui-page-sidebar bitbucket-theme"><ul id="assistive-skip-links" class="assistive"><li><a href="#aui-sidebar-content">Skip to sidebar navigation</a></li><li><a href="#aui-page-panel-content-body">Skip to content</a></li></ul><div id="page"><!-- start
```

The file name is "groups+users.yaml". What is the best way to read in yaml format for python to parse/process?

Comment: The content seems like an HTML page rather than a yaml file. Are you sure you have the correct url? Can you print(x) to see what that gives you?

Comment: print(x) shows:
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fe200a4dfd0>
Looks like "urllib.request.urlopen" didn't get the right thing.

Comment: try `print(x.read())`, it's probably the webpage with the file embedded and not the file itself, like github.

Comment: print(x.read()) displayed as html file...... sjc bidlvs for additional capacity","parents":[{"id":"e928f13fbb7247cb82db3ffdd180498aca15d28e","displayId":"e928f13fbb7"}],"properties":{"change":{"type":"MODIFY","path":"puppet/lvs/nessy+biddy.yaml"}}}, "puppet\\/lvs\\/nessy+biddy.yaml","source", \'#content .aui-page-panel-content\', \'file-content\',10,true,false,null);</script></body></html>'

Comment: Best way is to double check the url, sometimes if you give it some parameters it will return the yaml file. Otherwise, I would suggest to use BeautifulSoup to parse the response and get the yaml content that way. Another thing to check is the response status, whether it's 200. If not, this could be the error page.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```py
import requests
import yaml

# Retrieve the file content from the URL
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
# Convert bytes to string
content = response.content.decode("utf-8")
# Load the yaml
content = yaml.safe_load(content)
```